# How do I split an OCaml list into head and tail?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm just learning OCaml and right now, I use `match l with h::t ->` to split lists when I need to access the head. But I'm sure there *has* to be a better way to split a list this way. I can't seem to find much online. Maybe I'm not looking in the right way.

Comment: Did you try `List.hd l` and `List.tl l`?

Comment: @Antrikshy Why does there *have* to be a better way? What's better than pattern matching?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Ah. I didn't know it was considered a great way. I'm new to functional programming and it just felt kind of awkward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the best way.

There are functions `List.hd` and `List.tl` to get `hd` and `tl` but there is no function available in the standard library to get the head and tail in one move.  In addition `List.hd` and `List.tl` are unsafe: if you give an empty list to them, they raise runtime exceptions:

```
# List.hd [];;
Exception: Failure "hd".
```

You can use them safely if you are 100% sure that the argument cannot be empty, but your speculation is often not correct in practice.  `List.hd` and `tl` can be very good sources of bugs.

Using patterns with `let`: `let (h::t) = l in ...` is possible, but it also has a risk of runtime failures, but the compiler can tell you that your pattern is not exhaustive and lacks the handling of `[]`.

`match` can have multiple cases and you can cover the case for `[]`: `match l with [] -> ... | (h::t) -> ...`.  If you forget the case for `[]`, the compiler can warn you about it.

Answer (score 1):

The OCaml way for this issue is the expression

```
match l with
| [] -> some_expr
| x :: xs -> some_other_expr
```

- The worst solution is using `List.hd` or `List.hd`, leading to possible runtime exception.
- The second worse solution is an incomplete match such as `match l with x :: xs` leading also to the same runtime errors, but you at least get a compile time warning, with the matching case(s) you missed.

Note that you can ignore some parts of the matching if not used, 
so your code is self documenting:

```
let hd_option lst =
match lst with
| [] -> None
| x :: _ -> Some x (* the tail is not used, so I just don't name it *)
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know OCaml, but Haskell offers these, which you can probably translate easily:

```
-- I think ML might write this signature
-- uncons : 'a list -> ('a * 'a list) option
uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
uncons (x : xs) = Just (x, xs)
uncons [] = Nothing

maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe def f Nothing = def
maybe def f (Just x) = f x
```

Then you can write things like

```
drop1 :: [a] -> [a]
drop1 = maybe [] snd . uncons
```